# Collapse private section of a C++ class in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse CDT one can collapse sections to hide details. I would like to hide the details in the private section of a C++ class so that a printout does not display the implementation details.

How can I collapse the private section of this class?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no functionality like this.
What I do to fold regions in general is to define some as preprocessor branches.

You could surround your private area like.

```
class myClass
{
public:
    void myInterfaceFunc();

#ifndef PRIVATE_SECTION_CODE_FOLDER
private:
    void _secretUnderTheHoodLogic();
#endif
};
```

In Eclipse Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor -> Folding
You can enable folding of preprocessor branches